# Need to set the height of a webview based on the height of the content

Tags: webview, height, nativescript, marshalling

How can I get the height of the webview based on the content loaded.

The webview seems to grow to fit the content on Android, however the webview height is always 0 on ios unless set manually.

Unfortunately I have no way of knowing what the height should be to set it manually.

I've tried nativescript-webview-interface but this does not work on ios.

Is there marshalling/code for ios to retrieve the webview height or webview scrollheight after load?

Comment: The web page you load within WebView, is it a local file or a remote website? If it's remote site, do you own the access?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer with a simple method

**html:**

```
<WebView [src]="src" (loadFinished)="onLoadFinished($event)"></WebView>
```

**ts:**

```
import { EventData, WebView } from '@nativescript/core';
.
.
.
onLoadFinished(event: EventData) {
    const webView = <WebView>event.object;

    webView.style.height = 0;

    setTimeout(() => {
      webView.style.height = 'auto';
    }, 100);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put your webview in a `GridLayout` that has `rows=*, columns=*` to resolve the height by the grid layout.

```
<GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
  <WebView row="0" col="0" id="wv" height="100%"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the content needs to be included in a scrollview with other elements.